# Graphite: time per point precision

Tags: python, graphite

Is it possibile to store time per point with millisecond precision?

Since [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) is based on [Whisper](http://graphite.wikidot.com/whisper) I've took a look at whisper.py file. 
It contains:

```
UnitMultipliers = {
   's' : 1,
   'm' : 60,
   'h' : 60 * 60,
   'd' : 60 * 60 * 24,
   'y' : 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
}
```

so it seems that it's possibile to record events with a maximum precision of 1s.
How can I cope with a system that produces an event every 10ms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send the data to the carbon-aggregator daemon or Statsd. These are both aggregators, so they'd aggregate the millisecond data and write it out in a per second value. For carbon-aggregator, you'd have to config the aggregator with how you want the data gathered: sum, avg, etc. For Statsd, the api call determines the aggregation used, so you don't have to pre-configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that graphite is unable to store metrics at a 10ms interval you could try sending the data to the statsD system. Then flush the metrics from statsD to graphite.

You can find the statsD code on [github.com](https://github.com/etsy/statsd)

[Introduction to statsD on codeascraft.etsy.com](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/)