# Graphite / Graphiti-esque tool with millisecond precision, optional aggregation

Tags: visualization, time-series, graphite

I need a timeseries datastore and visualization platform where I can dump experiment data into hierarchical namespaces and then go back later for analysis. Saving graph templates, linking to graphs and other features to go from analysis to presentation would be very useful. Initially I was really excited to read about [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) and [Graphiti](https://github.com/paperlesspost/graphiti), because they appear to fit the bill. However, the events I'm tracking are milliseconds apart and I need to keep millisecond precision without aggregation or averaging. It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216736/graphite-time-per-point-precision) the only way to make Graphite play nice is to aggregate up from statsd to metrics per second, which will obscure the events I'm interesting in. Optional aggregation would be fine in some cases, but not always.

[Cube](http://square.github.com/cube/) takes events with millisecond timestamps, but [Cubism](http://square.github.com/cubism/) appears to be a rich library and not a full-fledged platform like Graphite. It also appears to be heavily real-time oriented. If I can't find a good stack to meet my needs I'll probably use Cube to store my data, but visualizing it with batch scripts that generate piles and piles of matplotlib graphs is not fun.

Am I misinformed, or is there another framework out there which will give me decent analysis/interactivity with an arbitrary time granularity?

Answer (score 0):

Cubism.js is just a front-end for Graphite (and other back-ends, like Cube), so I think it would fit your needs.

You would need to setup a Graphite system to store your metrics (rather than Cube) with the appropriate level of detail (eg. millisecond), and then use Cubism's [Graphite context](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Graphite) to display it with the same step value.